# Android 4.0.3 ICS ArrayAdapter notifyDataSetChanged does not update the ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

There are many questions about listviews and their adapters but I'm pretty sure I use it correctly. However I now have a listview that doesn't (always) update properly on Android 4.0.3 (ICS, and only in some certain layouts).

Code:

In the onCreate of the Activity:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list);
mArrayAdapter = new CustomListAdapter( this, R.layout.row_layout);
// We update it manually, but leaving this default doesn't work either
mArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange( false);
mListView.setAdapter( mArrayAdapter);
```

From separate threads I receive new data which I have to append, replace, insert in the adapter. For simplicitly I now use the total replace example by using the clear:

```
private void updateList() {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      mArrayAdapter.clear();
      for (CustomItem item: mLastReceivedItems) {
        mArrayAdapter.add(item);
      }
      mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  });
}
```

When new items are received they are shown in the list but if an update is received without any items. The view is still showing items while the adapter is really empty.

The code still works on Android 2.3.7 and I also can't reproduce it when I use an other layout but I can't see many differences that could matter.

Did anyone find any layout parameter or adapter function to workaround this bug without losing much performance?

Comment: what is the type and function of responseRequester?

Comment: Just an item of any type. It is not relevant what kind of types are used in the adapter and listview

Comment: I did not ask you whether it is relevant or not. I am asking what is its type and functions? Is it only a data container? Show its code

Comment: It is a data class with some String members

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround as temporary fix by setting the same adapter on the listview every time I update the data so the listview will remove all its 'SMART' view re-using:

```
private void updateList() {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      mArrayAdapter.clear();
      for (CustomItem item: mLastReceivedItems) {
        mArrayAdapter.add(item);
      }
      mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      // FIXME: Temp fix for ICS:
      mListView.setAdapter( mListView.getAdapter());
    }
  });
}
```

I hope someone knows where the problem is because this way we're not using the ListView.mRecycler anymore, so we're losing performance here.

Comment: I encountered this bug when I tried to change fontsize of the listview programatically. The listview rows did not resize in API 15 (4.0.3), but did in all other versions. Your solution solved it!